# Armazenar sessão do vídeo dentro de session ou cookie php

Tags: php, javascript, html5, session, cookies

Como faço para armazenar o tempo da visualização de um vídeo(html5) em uma session ou cookie com php?

A ideia é criar uma mini plataforma de vídeos, e que seja armazenado o tempo de execução dentro de uma session | cookie, e quando o usuário voltar a vê-lo, seja iniciado de onde parou.

**OBS:** Referência para pegar o tempo atual do vídeo no w3schools

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_currenttime

Comment: Opa, como é html5 talvez seja melhor você salvar isso somente no storage do navegador, de uma olhada: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar o código atual do seu videoplayer, para facilitar pra quem for responder. Sem a implementação atual, fica muito aberta a questão.

Comment: Olá @Bacco, ainda não tem nada desenvolvido, mas irei iniciar o desenvolvimento e editar a pergunta, inserindo o código do que já foi feito pra quem poder colaborar.

Comment: @IgorSilva fica melhor, pq senão alguém responde algo com um código diferente do que você vai usar, aí a resposta não te serve, e a pessoa que ajudou acaba perdendo tempo. Realmente se você deixar o problema mais concentrado na armazenagem, valoriza pra todos.